# Issue with newly downloaded Android Studio 3.0 Canary 8

Tags: macos-sierra, android-studio-3.0

[image: error's screenshot]

What should I edit in build.gradle or wrapper file to solve this?

### My build.gradle file

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXH4L.png)

### My gradle-wrapper.properties file -

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip
```

Comment: Click the links?

Comment: not working, it's not the issue with internet

Comment: I never said it was. The link only explains that it's required to download Gradle libraries